# Why iOS silent push triggers application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: when app is in background

Tags: ios, background, timeout, launch, silentpush

I have some network requests with 15s timeout in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. I found the following odd situation.

T1: app entered background by pressing home button
T2: app received silent push and executed `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, then send requests
T3(> T2 + 15s): user taps app icon. All requests in T2 are timeout immediately.

My problem is why `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` was triggered in that situation and how to debug(reproduce this situation, because all above are in logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silent push can launch suspended app (which has been properly killed by iOS system due to memory tight, not the user kill manually) to background. In this case, lifecycle of the app becomes:

1. `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
2. `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
3. `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

Apple document: [About the Background Execution Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/about_the_background_execution_sequence)

Answer (score 1):

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called if your app is suspend or killed and you got the notification. Your application might have crashed in background and that's way `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is being called.

To debug that scenario, do the following.

1. Click on the target and select `Edit Scheme`
       [image]
2. Select Launch to `Wait for executable to be launched`
   [image]
3. Run the app.

   [image]

Now you can add break points in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and send notification to your device. Once device receives notification you can do the debugging.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but the breakpoint was not executed when receive silent notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can check app state to determine whether the app was launched from background when it received a notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo { 
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground ) { 
        //opened from a push notification when the app was on background
     } 
}
```

Edit::

There's nothing to debug here, it is intended functionality.

If you want to handle it differently, you can look for

> UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey

Inside of launch options, and do whatever work you need to when the app is launched from a notification.

Comment: Thank you, but you may need to understand my question.